# URL wrapping (line breaking) in csvreader tables

Tags: longtable, urls, csv

I am trying to create a table by reading a CSV file with 'csvreader'. The CSV file contains one URL per row, some of the URLs are too long, so the aspect is awful, since some of the URLs invades the next field.

Any suggestion to fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: \usepackage{url} could help... A MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would help also because we could see how to pass the `url`s in a `hyperref` command or something simmilar

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.